# How to groupby average and extract the last item in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, average

I want to extract the closing balance for the week across different date from the below dataframe

```
     Date     Week  Balance
  2017-02-12    6   50000.46
  2017-02-12    6   49531.46
  2017-02-12    6   48108.46    
  2017-05-12    19  21558.96
  2017-08-12    32  21561.1
  2018-02-05    6   2816.20
  2018-02-06    6   78.53
  2018-02-07    6   39.53
  2018-08-12    32  21561.1
```

Expected output is:

```
     Date     Week  Balance
  2017-02-12    6   48108.46    
  2017-05-12    19  21558.96
  2018-02-07    6   39.53
  2018-08-12    32  21561.1
```

I tried to use the `.last()` attribute of groupby function but I get multiple returns for the same week

```
weekly = df.groupby(["Transaction Date",'Week']).last().Balance
weekly

 Date.           week      Balance

2017-02-12        6        48108.46
2017-03-12        10       46802.46
2017-04-12        15       39588.46
2017-05-12        19       21558.96
2018-02-03        5        24699.73
2018-02-04        5          103.20
2018-02-05        6         2816.20
2018-02-06        6           78.53
2018-02-07        6           39.53
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to check for consecutive rows and keep the last one:

```
df.loc[df['Week'] != df['Week'].shift(-1)]
```

Output:

```
|    | Date       |   Week |   Balance |
|---:|:-----------|-------:|----------:|
|  2 | 2017-02-12 |      6 |  48108.46 |
|  3 | 2017-05-12 |     19 |  21558.96 |
|  4 | 2017-08-12 |     32 |  21561.10 |
|  7 | 2018-02-07 |      6 |     39.53 |
|  8 | 2018-08-12 |     32 |  21561.10 |
```

Comment: I don't thing that is what I 'm trying to achieve here.

I want to get the weekly average balance and to achieve that, I first need to get the balance across the different weeks in a calendar year, then average the entire result

Comment: The question you phrased is "I want to extract the closing balance for the week". This answers your question and meets your expected output. Please put the additional question in a new Stackoverflow post.